# karate-config.js failed after update of karate-core

Tags: karate

I'm trying to update my karate project with the newest version of karate-junit5 library.
In the [documentation](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#maven) for Maven it's mentioned that only one dependency is required to run karate.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
    <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Previously I was using karate-jersey and karate-junit4 and everything was working flawless.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
    <artifactId>karate-jersey</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intuit.karate/karate-junit5 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
    <artifactId>karate-junit4</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I managed to update karate-junit4 to karate-junit5 but I see that karate-core is still using 0.9.6

When I want to replace jersey with karate-core 1.3.0 and run my tests I have an error with loading my karate-config.js

> karate-config.js failed
> js failed:

`org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: SyntaxError: Unnamed:82:0 Expected ) but found function`

This is strange because I didn't change anything besides the dependencies.

Do I still have to use karate-jersey in my project? The documentation doesn't mention this.

I tried to update the dependency to the newest version. Now I got a failing karate-config.js

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as `karate-jersey`. Get rid of that dependency, the HTTP client is now built-in.

Since you are upgrading from such an old version, you need to read all the release notes. For example this one: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide#java-projects

But let's hope you get by with just this one change. Else be prepared to scan all the release notes. The JS engine has changed, but all those who kept tracking the project and tried RC versions (we spend a lot of time on this) have been having a smooth experience.

I guess this is what folks call "technical debt" ;)

Comment: There's something wrong with loading the karate-config.js - I'm using this function within the file
`function base64(creds) {
    var Base64 = Java.type('java.util.Base64');
    var encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(creds.getBytes());
    return 'Basic ' + encoded;
}`

Are there some restrictions for this right now? I see that when I comment this out it runs properly.

Comment: @user20103775 follow this process and you'll get a solution sooner: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue